# What was the device used to knock out Hank and the others?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

After the explosion at the mansion, Stryker arrives and orders one of his men to use what looks like an oversized megaphone to knock out our friends.

**What was this device?**

---

As there's no description (yet) of said device, perhaps something similar was used in the comics?

Comment: I believe it is called a plot device.

Comment: It should be noted that in Days of Future Past, he did work very closely with Trask, who had already successfully created devices capable of locating nearby mutants; not outside the realm of possibility that the Sentinels weren't his only creations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device appears to be a "stun gun" (not very helpful I know). Free lance artist [Bartol Rendulić](https://www.artstation.com/bartoleum) posted some [concept art](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/AEDeV) of the weapons online. I can't actually find any direct proof that Bartol did indeed work on *X-Men: Apocalypse* but the weapon in question does match the concept art posted by Bartol (that's not direct evidence in itself as it could have been drawn afterwards).

However, compare the device shown in the film and the concept art below.

[image: The device is used in the film] [image: Concept art of the device]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

If this is indeed actual concept art for the film there is also a small discrepancy with it, in that the concept art shows it being used to fire stun disks rather than shooting a sonic pulse of sorts.

[image: Concept art of the stun gun firing the disks]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

It's also worth checking out the link with the full concept art as it gives designs for a smaller model and a handheld pistol version that fires darts.

---

I can't find any comic inspiration for the device and can't source what is mentioned in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/223053/58193) so it may have been designed solely for the film.